# fix size of both columns in <af:selectManyShuttle>

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

How do we fix size of each of the columns of . Currently it auto-stretches depending upon the highest length of the data in all the rows. If there is no data, both columns get very small in size

Comment: Use ADF Skinning and read this: https://community.oracle.com/thread/919887

Answer (score 1):

Use `contentStyle` property and set desired width using px.

However, be aware that because of browser CSS precedence rules, CSS rendered on a DOM element takes precedence over external stylesheets like the skin file. Therefore skins will not be able to override what you set on this attribute.

http://jdevadf.oracle.com/adf-richclient-demo/docs/tagdoc/af_selectManyShuttle.html